# How can I optimise the running speed of following VBA code?

Tags: vba, optimization

I want to improve the efficiency of following VBA code. What i can think about is to use "With" and "End With" in the code. Is there any thing else I can do to optimise the code?

Thanks!

```
 Sub ONLY_CORP_Lives_Premiums()
Dim row_phil, row_phl, row_eveeb, row_evenb As Integer
Dim row_indiv, row_sme, row_corp As Integer
Dim row As Variant
Dim row_start, row_end As Integer
Dim i, k As Integer
Dim start_time, end_time

start_time = Now()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Sheets("SETUP").Range("J32") = Sheets("SETUP").Range("J28")

Sheets("LIVES PROJECTION").Activate
row_phil = Application.CountIf(Range("B1237:B1048576"), "PHIL" & "*")
row_phl = Application.CountIf(Range("B1237:B1048576"), "PHL" & "*") + row_phil
row_eveeb = Application.CountIf(Range("B1237:B1048576"), "EVEEB" & "*") + row_phl
row_evenb = Application.CountIf(Range("B1237:B1048576"), "EVENB" & "*") + row_eveeb
row = Array(0, row_phil, row_phl, row_eveeb, row_evenb)

For i = LBound(row) To (UBound(row) - 1)

    row_start = row(i) + 34
    row_end = row(i + 1) - 1 + 34
    row_indiv = Application.CountIf(Range("d" & row_start & ":d" & row_end), "INDIV")
    row_sme = Application.CountIf(Range("d" & row_start & ":d" & row_end), "SME")
    row_corp = Application.CountIf(Range("d" & row_start & ":d" & row_end), "CORP")
        For k = row_start + row_indiv + row_sme - 34 To row_start + row_indiv + row_sme + row_corp - 1 - 34
        With Sheets("LIVES PROJECTION")
        .Range("B12:G12").Value = .Range("B34:G34").Offset(k, 0).Value
        .Range("B12:FM26").Calculate
        End With
        Sheets("PREMIUMS PROJECTION").Range("B12:FM26").Calculate
        Sheets("LIVES PROJECTION").Range("H34:FM34").Offset(k, 0).Value = Sheets("LIVES PROJECTION").Range("H12:FM12").Value
        Sheets("PREMIUMS PROJECTION").Range("H34:FM34").Offset(k, 0).Value = Sheets("PREMIUMS PROJECTION").Range("H12:FM12").Value
        Next k
Next i
''
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Sheets("SETUP").Range("J33") = Sheets("SETUP").Range("J28")
Calculate!
end_time = Now()
Sheets("SETUP").Range("j50") = DateDiff("s", start_time, end_time)

End Sub
```

Comment: Declaring variables to a specific type helps, but your current declarations only give a specific type to the last variable on each line: in VBA each variable needs a type, or they will be Variant by default.  Also a good idea to use Long instead of Integer (which tops out at 32,767 and is risky for ranges in Excel 2007+)  Use variables to hold references to each of your sheets, and also for any range you use more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to calculate so much inside `For .. Next` loop? If you don't, switch to `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning, and calculate once at the end. If you do need to calculate during execution of your code, try to modify it so it calculates as little as possible.
Using `With .. End With` doesn't really help so much. If at all.